# Strip paragraph text before cue word

Tags: javascript, java, rhino, nashorn

I have a text like this:

```
Last login: today


cat file
testMachine:root:/root# cat file
File contents
testMachine:root:/root#
```

And I need to retrieve the information like this:

```
testMachine:root:/root# cat file
File contents
```

Stripping away the last line is easy, but the amount of lines I need to remove at start is arbitrary, and I need to remove everything up until the first cue word, which is the machine name, that is known and stored.

I have tried `substring()` but it strips line by line instead of treating the whole text as one, and removes the host name too, which should remain there. I tried `replace()` too, but I am not familiar with regex, so the result is a memory exception.

EDIT 1: It seems to be important to note that using a JS for Java engine (In this case I'm using Rhino) means the result isn't the same as you get in web. This was found out after an answer below, which works perfectly on web, doesn't even run on the desktop app.

Comment: You can use `paragraph.indexOf(cueword)` to figure out the first occurrence of `cueword` in `paragraph`. Then use `substring`

Comment: As I said, I already did that and it doesn't work. The result is the same with the cue word removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const text = ` 
Last login: today


cat file
testMachine:root:/root# cat file
File contents
testMachine:root:/root#`;
const cueWord = "testMachine:root"
const idx = text.indexOf(cueWord);
let restOftheString = text.substring(idx).split("\n");
restOftheString.pop()
console.log(restOftheString.join("\n"))
```

Comment: On the one hand, this works as expected when I run the script. On the other hand it doesn't work on my application. I must use it on a JS for Java engine, and I thought it would be the same result... apparently it's not. Nashorn returns errors and can't run the script, Rhino works after I remove the `let` operator. I definitely should have tagged this question as such, but I didn't know it was part of the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because the problem turned out to be related to the tool, not the JS code, and your answer was technically correct.